# Grouping dates by weeks using reduce()

Tags: javascript, datetime, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a function `groupWeeks(dates)` using `reduce` that allows me to group an array of objects `{ date: '2019-03-11', count: 8 }` by weeks.

The following code works fine. Is there a way to refactor it? It seems to me that my solution is unnecessarily complex. Please ignore `Date.prototype.getWeekNumber` and `getWeekStart(date)`.

```js
const dates = [
  { date: '2019-02-24', count: 10 },
  { date: '2019-02-25', count: 11 },
  { date: '2019-02-26', count: 12 },
  { date: '2019-03-09', count: 8 },
  { date: '2019-03-10', count: 7 },
  { date: '2019-03-11', count: 6 },
  { date: '2019-04-14', count: 3 },
  { date: '2019-04-15', count: 2 },
  { date: '2019-04-16', count: 4 },
  { date: '2019-04-22', count: 5 }
];

/**
 * Returns the week number for this date.  dowOffset is the day of week the week
 * "starts" on for your locale - it can be from 0 to 6. If dowOffset is 1 (Monday),
 * the week returned is the ISO 8601 week number.
 * @param int dowOffset
 * @return int
 */
Date.prototype.getWeek = function(dowOffset) {
  /*getWeek() was developed by Nick Baicoianu at MeanFreePath: http://www.epoch-calendar.com */

  dowOffset = typeof dowOffset == 'int' ? dowOffset : 0; //default dowOffset to zero
  var newYear = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  var day = newYear.getDay() - dowOffset; //the day of week the year begins on
  day = day >= 0 ? day : day + 7;
  var daynum =
    Math.floor(
      (this.getTime() -
        newYear.getTime() -
        (this.getTimezoneOffset() - newYear.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60000) /
        86400000
    ) + 1;
  var weeknum;
  //if the year starts before the middle of a week
  if (day < 4) {
    weeknum = Math.floor((daynum + day - 1) / 7) + 1;
    if (weeknum > 52) {
      nYear = new Date(this.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
      nday = nYear.getDay() - dowOffset;
      nday = nday >= 0 ? nday : nday + 7;
      /*if the next year starts before the middle of
           the week, it is week #1 of that year*/
      weeknum = nday < 4 ? 1 : 53;
    }
  } else {
    weeknum = Math.floor((daynum + day - 1) / 7);
  }
  return weeknum;
};

function getWeekStart(date) {
  var offset = new Date(date).getDay();
  return new Date(new Date(date) - offset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, 10);
}

function groupWeeks(dates) {
  const groupsByWeekNumber = dates.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    const today = new Date(item.date);
    const weekNumber = today.getWeek();

    // check if the week number exists
    if (typeof acc[weekNumber] === 'undefined') {
      acc[weekNumber] = [];
    }

    acc[weekNumber].push(item);

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return groupsByWeekNumber.map(function(group) {
    return {
      weekStart: getWeekStart(group[0].date),
      count: group.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        return acc + item.count;
      }, 0)
    };
  });
}

console.log(groupWeeks(dates));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said to ignore `getWeekStart()`, but I'm afraid I can't do that.  It appears that the intention of `getWeekStart()` is to take a date string (in YYYY-MM-DD form) and find the Sunday that starts the week (in YYYY-MM-DD form).  However, depending on the time zone in which the code is executed, it may actually find the Monday, or possibly a Saturday instead.

The problem is that

- [`new Date("YYYY-MM-DD")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) interprets the date as a UTC timestamp:

  > **Note:** parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that **date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local**.
- [`date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week for the specified date **according to local time**, where 0 represents Sunday.
- [`date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) works in UTC:

  > The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format ([ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively). **The timezone is always zero UTC offset**, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

For the code to be reliably correct, you must work consistently in UTC — in other words, call [`date.getUTCDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay) instead.

Furthermore, I'd rename `getWeekStart()` to `weekStart()`.  The "get" prefix implies that you are fetching something that already exists.  However, you are actually computing something, so the prefix is superfluous, perhaps even misleading.

Comment: I really appreciate looking into details. I did not realize it could be a problem.